# I want to display data in <h4> instead of <input> in bootstrap modal during delete

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I want the `location_name` to show as an `<h4>` instead of `<input>`

I tried adding id & name like this `<h4 name="location_name" id="location_name">` but didn't work.

**My Modal:**

```
{{-- Modal Delete --}}
<div class="modal-info-delete modal fade show" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-info" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action=" {{ route('worklocations_table.destroy',$location->id) }} " method="post">
            {{ method_field('delete') }}
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{-- Modal Body --}}
            <div class="modal-body">  
                <div class="atbd-notice__content">
                    <div class="atbd-notice__top text-center mt-20">
                        <div class="atbd-notice__icon bg-danger">
                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation color-white"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="atbd-notice__text">
                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this location?</p>
                            <div class="mt-15">
                            <h4 >Location Name</h4>

                            <div></div>
                                
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" id="id">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location_name" id="location_name">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{-- Modal Buttons --}}
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-squared btn-outline-primary">Yes, delete</button>          
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-squared btn-outline-light" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>         
            </div>
            
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{-- Modal Delete - End --}}
```

**Script:**

```
<script>

    $('#delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event){

        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var id = button.data('id')
        var location_name = button.data('location_name')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(id);
        modal.find('.modal-body #location_name').val(location_name);
    })

</script>
```

Here's how it looks with the input tag

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can pass `location_name` value to h4 tag using something like `modal.find('.modal-body h4').html(location_name);`

Comment: Glad to help. Regards!